# Constructor for Hibernate Entity class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my domain Entity class I have an attribute that I want to use as the primary key (`GenerationType.AUTO`) {for use with the JPA Criteria API}.  I would like to define a constructor for this Entity class, which will initialize all attributes, except the primary key attribute, since Hibernate will provide this value.

In other words, the constructor will leave the *Primary Key* attribute undefined. Personally I don’t see any issues, but I want to get this approach vetted by the experts.

**Question**

- Is it a good practice to define an Entity constructor that leaves the attribute mapped to the primary key *undefined*, while initializing other attributes?

Comment: It's totally fine. You're free to initialize your entities the way you want to, and a constructor is a standard way to do that. Just remember that you need a no-arg constructor too (even a not public one).

Answer (score 2):

The [JPA specification document](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) (version 2.2) holds the answer in *Section 2.4*, page 31:

> The value of its primary key uniquely identifies an entity instance within a persistence context and to `EntityManager` operations as described in Chapter 3, “Entity Operations”. **The application must not change the value of the primary key [10]**. The behavior is *undefined* if this occurs.
>
> [10] *This includes not changing the value of a mutable type that is primary key or an attribute of a composite primary key.*

Therefore, using a constructor to initialize or set the value of a primary key may not a good idea as "*undefined behavior*" might result from it.

Keep in mind that - by the JPA spec - a no-arg constructor must also be provided in each entity class with a custom constructor (as described in your question). Search the specification for "constructor" for further details, especially *Section 2.1*.

IMHO, this should guide you in making a good design choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is that relevant? The OP doesn't want to initialize the ID. And anyway, the paragraph you quoted is about **changing** the value of the primary key. Not about initializing the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo)

> The entity class must have a public or protected no-argument constructor. **It may define additional constructors as well.**

and further

> JPA requires that this constructor be defined as public or protected. Hibernate, for the most part, does not care about the constructor visibility, as long as the system SecurityManager allows overriding the visibility setting. That said, the constructor should be defined with at least package visibility if you wish to leverage runtime proxy generation.

But look also at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-wrapper). It is useful sometimes to have an entity id among of constructor arguments.